# My grand-father emigrated to South-Africa and then to Lebanon, am I a British citizen?

Tags: united-kingdom

My grand-father, his father and brothers of my father went to Johannesburg in South Africa in the late 1890s or early 1900. They all had British passports.

When my grand-father returned to Lebanon and got married he never transferred the passport to his children and so we ended up not having the nationality. Is there a way to be able to claim it or is it gone?

My father and his two brothers all died.

Comment: You can use https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen for a first opinion. The rules are rather complex and I don't know them well but based on what you wrote I suspect you are not a citizen. Being born in the UK or registered in infancy is quite important and you can't trace back British citizenship through several generations after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of that is even close to what you are looking for is the [UK Ancestry visa](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/overview). However, this visa requires that:

- you are a Commonwealth citizen
- your grandfather was born in the UK

among other requirements, such as intending to live and work in the UK. From your description, it sounds like you are not a Commonwealth citizen and therefore would not be eligible for this type of visa.